# why CoreLocation unable to fetch new GPS data and Mapkit display this old GPS data

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am working on MapKit and core location to display my current GPS location.
The code is working ok but with some problems.

The problem is as follows:

1. I turn on my app in an open area like on the roadside. The app is able to get my current GPS location and display it on the Map.
2. I walk into a building with the app on. When inside, I launch the page to show the GPS location. It shows my previous GPS location. As I know, when I am inside the building, the Mapkit and Corelocation should not be able to get GPS. But in this case, it shows my previous GPS data!
3. I walk out of the building with the app on. In the open space I launch the page to show my current GPS location but the app is unable to get my new GPS location but displays the previous GPS data. In this case the app should fetch a new GPS location. I have to try a few times to launch the page (Navigate from GPS-VC to home-VC, from home click a button to launch the GPS-VC to get GPS).

Why is the GPS so slow even though I am in the open space with good signal strength?

Is there a difference to call these methods:

1. `LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`
2. `LocationManager.requestLocation()`

Here the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!

var locationMgr : CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidload(){

    if(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() )
    {
       locationMgr = CLLocationManager()
       locationMgr.delegate = self
       locationMgr.desriedAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
       locationMgr.requestWhenInuseAuthorization()
       locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLoction: CLLocation = locations[0]

    let latitude = userLoction.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = userLoction.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    let dropin = MKPointAnnotation()
    dropin.coordinate = location
    droping.title = "Here"

    self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.Map.addAnnotation(dropin)
    self.Map.showsUserLocation = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve all 3 of your issues but I spotted the following issues in your delegate method:

1. the locations array is sorted in ascending time order so locations.last will contain the most recent location.
2. This method might be called with old cached values so you need to check the timestamp of the location to decide if it's worth using.

Comment: This sounds logical. Will investigate the location data. Will get back here later.